# Facebook Graph API returns false

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with friend requests. When the user sends a friend request, I get a **request_id** as a response. However, when i use this **request_id** ( XXXX) as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/?access_token=YYYYYYYYY
```

it returns:

```
false
```

the **access_token** seems to be the right one( the one used here is for example only), am i missing something ? what does **false** mean? how do i get the JSON object as the return data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the last slash:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXX?access_token=YYYYYYYYY
```

Also try it with an application access token.

Comment: I tried without the '/' at the end, but it still gives 'false'. can you please let me know what is an 'application access token' ? The access_token i am using is the one that the application gets when the user is authenticated.

Comment: yes, works. The request_ids require the Application Access Token as against the User Access Token. Application Access Token is also documented as 'signed app secret' under Request Dialog.

Comment: @lugbug: Glad it helped! and sorry for the delay but my testing environment wasn't setup yesterday to create an example for you.

Comment: Could you give a slightly more detailed explanation of what you did to fix it. Was it simply using the sign app secret instead of the user access token?

Comment: no the [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/). also read my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/)

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you have any restriction in your page config. I guess any restriction by country or by age.

Remove the condition in the FB page and try again.

**UPDATE:**

Is just my guessing but I assume that the reason because it return false in case of restrictions is because FB could not verify is the request complies with the page restrictions. I solve the problem using OAuth 2.0

[Facebook docs for OAuth 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

And here some code to make the life easier:

FILE 1:

```
require_once( 'oauth2callback/index.php' );

// Get likes from FB using auth
$likes = do_auth_FB( '[Object name]' );
echo 'Likes en Facebook: ' . $likes . '<br/>';
```

FILE 2: (oauth2callback/index.php)

```
function do_auth_FB( $objectName) {

    // Setting required variables
    $fbAppID = '[App ID]';
    $fbSecret = '[App secret]';
    $redirectURI = '[URL to redirect]';
    $objectName = '[Object name]';

    // Getting code var
    $code = $_GET["code"];

    // Calling for code
    if( empty( $code ) ) {
        $urlcode = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?'
       . 'client_id=' . $fbAppID . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode( $redirectURI )
       . '&client_secret=' . $fbSecret;

        echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $urlcode . "'</script>";
    }

    // Calling for token
    $urlToken = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
       . 'client_id=' . $fbAppID . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode( $redirectURI )
       . '&client_secret=' . $fbSecret . '&code=' . $code;

    $response = file_get_contents( $urlToken );
    $outputResponse = null;
    parse_str( $response, $outputResponse );

    // Calling for the required object
    $graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $objectName . '?access_token='
       . $outputResponse["access_token"];

    $objectStream = json_decode( file_get_contents( $graph_url ) );

    return $objectStream->likes;
}
```

In the example only returns the page likes

Comment: That was totally my problem.  With or without my app access_token the api returns false as long as there are any restrictions.  Where's that documented?

Comment: @MrRogers: In my case was test and error. Sometimes FB documentations is not as good as should be ;). I update my answer trying to help how to solve it.