# Facebook graph API returns FALSE when using access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application I'm trying to test for expired access tokens. When making a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1234?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx
```

it always returns `FALSE`

What's strange is that when copying the url and using it within a web browser it returns the expected result instead of false. Can't seem to find any documentation within facebook docs as to why it would ever return `FALSE` and how to resolve it.

I have found one other question on stackoverflow which "answers" the question but the answer isn't very clear and I'm unable to comment to enquire about it. Here's the link [Facebook Graph API returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011027/facebook-graph-api-returns-false)

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Edit:

When making a request to Facebook it's meant to return JSON object. Response code I receive is `0` when making a request to the url `https://graph.facebook.com/1234?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx` and response body is `FALSE` as mentiond above. The code I've used is as follows:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($curl_response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($curl_response, $header_size);
$response_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

When running the above code I receive the FALSE response and http code of 0.
When I copy and paste the url into any browser what happens is described below:
If the access token is valid it returns user data in JSON format. `$response_code` is `200` and the value of `$body` is supposed to look as follows:

```
{
    id: "1234",
    first_name: "Name",
    gender: "male",
    last_name: "Surname",
    locale: "en_US",
    middle_name: "Middle Name",
    name: "Name Middle Name Surname",
    username: "name.surname"
}
```

If the access token is invalid it returns the error in JSON format. `$response_code` depends on the error but in most cases and in this case its a 403. Example data (value of `$body`:

```
{
    error: {
        message: "Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.",
        type: "OAuthException",
        code: 190,
        error_subcode: 458
    }
}
```

I know the response code 0 usually means a request was never made or curl isn't supported or something like that however, when I make `$url = "http://www.google.co.za";` using the same code I get a response code of `200` and the response body returned is the html code of the website. So I know it works, I've tested it with 3 different urls.

Comment: what is the format of the response (in the browser, when it works) ?  and please provide the code you're using to make the call.

Comment: @Fosco Done with the edits, I hope I haven't missed anything. I appreciate the help.