# Facebook Graph API file_get_contents() returns false

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents, php-5.6

I'm currently trying to do a Facebook API call to fetch Facebook Lead data and didn't find anything that would fix my problem. I would like to be able to parse the JSON response I get from the browser at least!

Here's what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/tixastronauta/0b9c3b409a7ba96edffc

Here's the simplified code:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

try {
    $str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/444444444444?access_token=<token>';
    $a = file_get_contents($str);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'error: '.$e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($a);
print_r(json_decode($a));

echo '</pre>';
```

Which gives me this:

```
bool(false)
```

Accessing it through Chrome gives me a JSON response with an error like so:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '444444444444' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "A+7XDwKGBhW"
   }
}
```

This didn't help: [Facebook Graph API returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011027/facebook-graph-api-returns-false)

Any idea?

Comment: What is the value of `$a`?

Comment: what is 44444? Is it a form ID? Page ID? Account ID?

Comment: @Dimi It's a Facebook Lead ID

Comment: `Unsupported get request` means either the id is not correct, or you have no rights to access the object with your access token and the permissions it contains.